# Почему не записывает текст в файл Java. Файл outputText создается, но он пустой. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Tags: filewriter

public static void fileWriter (ArrayList list)  {
System.out.println("Введите адрес файла для записи");

```
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
        String outputFileName = reader.readLine();

             BufferedWriter writter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName));
                for (String value : list) {
                    writter.write(value + "\n");
                }
            }
             catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `finally` блок где закройте Ваш `BufferedWriter`. В таком случае Writer сбросит накопленные данные в файл.

```java
public static void fileWriter (ArrayList<String> list)  {
   System.out.println("Введите адрес файла для записи");
   BufferedWriter writer = null;
   try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
      String outputFileName = reader.readLine();
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName));
      for (String value : list) {
          writer.write(value + "\n");
      }
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (writer != null){
           writer.close();
       }
   }
}
```

Второй вариант:

```java
public static void fileWriter (ArrayList<String> list)  {
   System.out.println("Введите адрес файла для записи");
   try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
      String outputFileName = reader.readLine();
      try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))){
         for (String value : list) {
          writter.write(value + "\n");
         }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Подскажите пожалуйста почему writer.close(); выкидывает IOException и можно ли это исправить без throws IOException.

Comment: Он таким образом реализован. Этот метод может выбрасывать такое исключение, поэтому его надо либо описать в сигнатруе метода, либо сам вызов обернуть в трай-кетч, либо использовать контсрукцию трая с ресурсами и для врайтера (см. второй вариант)